# coc.nvim and formatSelected with golang not working

Tags: vimrc, plugin-coc

Getting this error message when running the shortcut:

> [coc.nvim]: Error on "formatSelected": formatRange provider not found
> for current buffer, your language server doesn't support it.

Using golang, here's the `CocConfig` (omitting irrelevant info):

```
{
  "languageserver": {
    "golang": {
      "command": "gopls",
      "rootPatterns": [
        "go.mod"
      ],
      "trace.server": "verbose",
      "filetypes": [
        "go"
      ],
      "initializationOptions": {
        "formatTool": "goimports"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Probably relevant config sections:

```
augroup mygroup
  autocmd!
  " Setup formatexpr specified filetype(s).
  autocmd FileType go,typescript,json setl formatexpr=CocAction('formatSelected')
  " Update signature help on jump placeholder.
  autocmd User CocJumpPlaceholder call CocActionAsync('showSignatureHelp')
augroup end

" Applying codeAction to the selected region.
" Example: `<leader>aap` for current paragraph
xmap <leader>a  <Plug>(coc-codeaction-selected)
nmap <leader>a  <Plug>(coc-codeaction-selected)
```

using

```
❯ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Feb 01 2022 09:16:32)
Included patches: 1-2269, 3612, 3625, 3669, 3741
```

Comment: Are you sure the formatter supports the formatting of a section of the code?

Comment: boooah, mind blown. I don't know! And probably not! `goimports` resp. `gofmt` are usually applied to whole files...

Comment: I'm using the ``:Format`` command to reformat the entire file